# How to get text from OARawTextBean

Tags: java, javabeans, oracle-apps

Which has text entered inside text field from UI page.

```
RawtxtBean  = (OARawTextBean)webBean.findIndexedChildRecursive("id1");
```

Now in controller code,I want to get text entered into the text field.

I've tried following option:

```
 String s = RawtxtBean.toString();
 String s = RawtxtBean.VALUE;
```

But both of these option are not returning the text.

Here I am using Oracle Application Framework, which is J2EE framework

Can someone please suggest me what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below methods to fetch the text entered in the bean.

```
String s = RawtxtBean.getText();
```

or

```
String s = RawtxtBean.getValue(pageContext);
```